# fish shell prompt not showing symbols correctly

Tags: fish

I've installed fish, and the agnoster theme througth oh-my-fish;
Now I have the prompt not showing correctly symbols;

[image: my fish prompt]

Can someone explain what's wrong?

Comment: Which font is your Terminal using?

Comment: I've tried also other fonts, no changes... Probably it's not related to this...

Comment: no you were right: the font I was using was not supporting powerline symbols

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was using a font not supporting powerline symbols;
after installing them, everything's all right;

I've used this guide to install powerline fonts:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/283908/how-can-i-install-and-use-powerline-plugin